# How to play Pokémon Go in China?

Tags: pokemon-go

Just got to China. (Got my game from the American app store.)

Maps are barren. No pokémon. No gyms. No pokéstops.

Forbes says: [Want To Play 'Pokémon GO' In China? You'd Better Give Up](http://www.forbes.com/sites/ywang/2016/07/13/want-to-play-pokemon-go-in-china-youd-better-give-up/#14e73d764d72)

> For the hit mobile game Pokémon GO to come to China, it would require nothing short of a total game redesign.

How to play Pokémon Go in China?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Want to play Pokemon GO in China? You'd better give up.

Pokemon GO requires the use of Google's servers and resources for the majority of the game. Google just so happens to be banned in China because *political reasons*.

Now, in theory, you could set up a VPN to the States or any non-censoring country. From there, you can access Google's servers, and therefore the game. Note that setting up a VPN is not in the scope of this site, so it's left as an exercise to the reader.

Additionally, Niantic will block the game from loading anything in "unsupported" countries at this time. Meaning, if you have a VPN set up and guaranteed working, Niantic may just not be spawning any Pokemon in your vicinity because there's supposed to be nobody there to catch them.

Comment: VPN still results in a barren pokémon-less map.

Comment: @user3306356 Where are you tunneling to, and what VPN provider (OpenVPN, L2TP, PPTP) are you using? Also, can you see Pokestops and Gyms?

Comment: 12VPN - USA - PPTP. Like I said in the Q: Maps are barren. No pokémon. No gyms. No pokéstops.

Comment: @user3306356 Okay, post edited. I think Niantic just doesnt have any spawns or anything in China yet.

Comment: Time to Location Faker then

Comment: @user3306356 That is how you get banned.